# Use Pytest with Django without using django-pytest 3rd party app

Tags: python, django, pytest, django-settings

Is it possible to use Pytest with Django without using django-pytest 3rd party app?

I had tried to set this up, but kept running into random errors, like pytest couldn't find the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.  Then I fixed the path, but the normal `python manage.py runserver` then couldn't find the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. I'm running:

```
Pytest 2.5.4
Python 3.4.0
Django 1.6.2
```

If it is possible, would you be able to provide a setup example of where to put the `tests/` directory, etc... within the project so `Pytest` works?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, py.test 2.5.4 does not exist afaik.

Anyway, assuming you mean to ask whether it is possible to avoid the pytest-django plugin to test Django using py.test: the short answer is no.

The long answer is yes, but it is extremely difficult to get it all to work and you will basically write at least a minimal version of pytest-django in the conftest.py file.  The pytest-django plugin was created specifically to work around all the weirdness which Django does with much global state and other hidden magic.

OTOH looking at the pytest-django source would probably help you  kickstart such an effort.  However you may consider thinking about what it is of pytest-django you do not like and maybe file an enhancement request to improve it.

Comment: thanks good advice. so there's some work to do, or I need to just use pytest-django!